# How can I put a function inside ORDER BY ABS(

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sql-order-by, ranking

Currently I have an SQL query which looks up acceptable matches and then sorts them using:

`ORDER BY ABS (itemranking - $rating)`

Is it possible to somehow modify the "item ranking" as the query is processed so that a condition can be added that says something like:

`if (category == '$category')`

subtract 1 from the ABS of item;

THEN `ORDER BY ABS` ?

I'm not sure if this is a quick answer for someone who knows the proper code, or if it's a bigger conceptual "how could I achieve this result" type of question.

Either way it might be helpful to have some context.  The goal is to sort a bunch of submissions so that they match a value "rating", but also to give a boost to items that are in the category the user is looking for.

A real life example (not my site):  A shopping site could offer a filter that searches for closest matches in terms of price, but acts as though all items within a certain category (e.g. "red") are $10 closer to being a match than they actually are.

Answer (score 1):

Why not go with the following type of SQL, making use of a CASE statement within the ORDER BY expression to dynamically order the results?

This is more of a SQL-oriented solution, so I'm not sure how applicable it is to your question.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY CASE Category 
           WHEN '$category' THEN ABS(ItemRanking - $rating - 1) 
           ELSE ABS(ItemRanking - $rating)
         END
```

Comment: I guess I am not familiar enough with SQL outside the functions I regularly use in PHP to understand exactly whats going on.

So I add a special case which seems to function like an if statement.  I suppose its the "else" statement that im lost on.  When does "ranking" get set?

Comment: @user187680: I've modified the query a bit to simplify it.  The CASE statement that I'm using within the ORDER BY clause is nothing more than a collection of IF statements which, in this case, depend on the fields in each row (Category and ItemRanking) and local PHP variables $category and $rating.  The value returned from this CASE statement is a straight number that can be sorted relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
Select if(category='$category', ABS (itemranking - $rating) - 1, ABS (itemranking - rating)) as calc 
FROM table 
ORDER BY calc
```

Answer (score 0):

As already metionned, the use of a test condition in a Select query is done by using the Case statement.  Beside the example already given, some other examples of code could be:

```
Order By ABS (itemranking - $rating) - 
  Case When category == '$category' Then 1 Else 0 End
```

or

```
Order By ABS (Case when category == '$category' then (itemranking - $rating - 1)
  Else (item - $rating) End)
```

Also, you don't mention if you are using MySQL or MS-SQL Server or some other sql-server. Some stuff that will work correctly with MySQL might not work with MS-SQL Server and vice-versa.